# Kusto query combining multiple rows into a single row based on Unique ID and where clause

Tags: join, kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-diagnostics

I have an Azure Logic App that logs to a Log Analytics Workspace.

There are 2 tracked properties that are written as custom values. These are written on different Rows as they are part of different steps.

If this was SQL, I'd do a conditional join to itself and then base my Where clause on said conditional join.

Sample Data:

| uniqueID | trackedproperty1 | trackedproperty2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 |  |
| 1 |  | word1 |
| 2 | 35 |  |
| 2 |  | word1.2 |
| 3 | 10 |  |
| 3 |  | word1.3 |
| 4 | 100 |  |
| 4 |  | word1.4 |

What I want to to do is get an output that shows all the uniqueIDs where trackedproperty1 is greater than a number - for the sake of argument - 25. e.g. the output would look like:

| uniqueID | trackedproperty1 | trackedproperty2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 35 | word1.2 |
| 4 | 100 | word1.4 |

I got as far as:

table
| summarize any(trackedproperty1), any(trackedproperty2) by uniqueID
| where trackedproperty1 >= 25

However, that causes the trackedproperty2 column to be blank.

As an additional consideration, eventually, I would like to be able to expand the contents of trackedproperty2 with a single drill-down (so the solution should bear that in mind) - currently it's in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself - ironically by trying to do something else - I kept getting an error when trying to extend a column - which was the column didn't exist.

when using the any() function, a new column is created with the name any_columnName - by moving my where clause in the Kusto query to after the summarize step and referencing *the new column name* - it then filtered as I expected.

table
| summarize any(trackedproperty1), any(trackedproperty2) by uniqueID
| where any_trackedproperty1 >= 25

This generated the results that I was wanting/expecting

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
datatable(uniqueID:long, trackedproperty1:long, trackedproperty2:string)
[
    1, 24, "",
    1, long(null),  'word1',
    2, 35, "",
    2, long(null),  'word1.2',
    3, 10, "",  
    3, long(null),  'word1.3',
    4, 100, "",
    4, long(null),  'word1.4',
]
| summarize take_any(trackedproperty1), take_any(trackedproperty2) by uniqueID
| where trackedproperty1 > 25
```

| uniqueID | trackedproperty1 | trackedproperty2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 35 | word1.2 |
| 4 | 100 | word1.4 |

Comment: Thanks, I actually just solved it whilst looking at something else.